# How many labeled trees are there if there're $4$ leaves that are set?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

> Let $T=(V,E)$ be a tree of $10$ labeled nodes numbered $1,2,3,\dots,10$ such that there're $4$ labeled leaves $1,2,3,4$ (there may be more leaves in addition to $1,2,3,4$). How many such trees are there and how many trees are there where the leaves are only $1,2,3,4$?

I'll start with the second part. If there're exactly $4$ leaves then for every node except for nodes $1,2,3,4$ we have: 
$$2\le \deg(v)\le 4$$
because if $\deg(v)=1$ then it's an additional leave and if $\deg(v)>4$ then there're more than $4$ leaves.

According to the handshaking lemma:
$$
\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v)=2|E|=2(|V|-1)=18
$$
We now need to find all possible combinations with repetitions of integers $2,3,4$ over $6$ bins ($6$ nodes remain after removal of $4$ leaves) such that their sum is $18-4=14$:
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=14,\quad 2\le x_i\le 4
$$
which can be solved using generating functions:
$$
(x^2+x^3+x^4)^6=14\\x^{12}(1+x+x^2)=14
$$
so we need to find the coefficient of $x^{2}$ in:
$$
\bigg(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\bigg)^6=\sum_{k=0}^6{6\choose k}(-1)^kx^{3k}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{i+5\choose i}x^6
$$
but it's impossible to find the coefficient from this because the powers of $x$ are too high.

I would've multiplied the result by $6!$ to account for order but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

And regarding the first part I would've found the number of labeled trees with at least the leaves $1,2,3,4$ by first choosing some ${6\choose 3}$ from $6$ nodes that are not $1,2,3,4$ and then using the same approach as above to count all combinations with repetitions and then subtract all that from the total $n^{n-2}$ possible labeled trees.

Comment: I now understand that it's incorrect to use my generating function because there're cases which are against conditions like having two 4-degree nodes, 4 3-degree nodes. But the trees can either contain a) one 4-degree node or b)2 nodes of degree 3. Then in case a) we have 10 degrees to distribute to 5 nodes of degree so would it be ${10+5-1\choose 10}$ and in case b)we need to distribute 8 degrees to 4 nodes so would it be  ${4+8-1\choose 8}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a labeled tree on $n$ vertices  the count of those where the first
$m$      are      leaves      is     obtained      using      [Pruefer
codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence), which have
the property  that the degree of  a vertex in the  tree resulting from
the code is one more than the  number of times it appears in the code.
Thus the fact that  the $m$ nodes are leaves means  they do not appear
in the Pruefer code. Hence there remain

$$(n-m)^{n-2}$$

possible codes.  If these $m$ leaves  are the only ones  all the other
nodes must appear in the Pruefer code. We get using Stirling numbers

$$(n-m)! \times {n-2\brace n-m}.$$

**Remark.** I noticed the link to the OEIS only now where OP says they
are not familiar  with Stirling numbers.  I trust  the Wikipedia entry
on Pruefer codes is sufficient. With the Stirling numbers we partition
the $n-2$  slots in the Pruefer  code into sets for  the $n-m$ values,
which correspond  to the nodes  and are  then guaranteed to  appear at
least once.  Here we have ordered set partitions however and hence the
multiplier of $(n-m)!.$  E.g. when we fill four slots  with two values
$1$ and  $2$ and have a  set partition into two  sets namely $\{1,3\}$
and $\{2,4\}$  then placing $1$  in the former  and $2$ in  the latter
slots is not the same as $2$ in the former and $1$ in the latter.  The
fact that  Stirling numbers count  unordered set partitions  into into
non-empty sets is all we need to know here.

**Addendum.**  OP asks for  clarification of closed form  at [OEIS
A055316](https://oeis.org/A055316).  Explanation  is simply  that OEIS
lists the formula  for the number of trees having  exactly $m$ leaves,
as opposed to trees where nodes $1$ to $m$ are the set of leaves. This
means  we need  to choose  the $m$  leaves from  the $n$  nodes first,
getting

$${n\choose m} \times (n-m)! \times {n-2\brace n-m}
= \frac{n!}{m!} \times {n-2\brace n-m}.$$

Comment: In the oeis.org link the formula for the problem is $\frac{n!}{4!}\cdot S(n-2, n-4)$ but why in the formula you wrote is the fraction part missing? Also if I develop the Stirling formula I see that there're inclusion/exclusion logic behind it: $6^8-{6\choose 5}5^8+{6\choose 4}4^8-\dots$. Can you please explain the intuition behind it? What it looks like to me is: in the beginning there're 8 cells and each cell may have each of the 6 value, then we choose 5 values and each of those 5 values may be in 8 cells, etc.

Comment: So do the values represent the nodes we select while there're always 8 cells in Prufer sequence? But how does this relate to our problem?

Comment: Stirling numbers of the second kind may indeed by computed by inclusion-exclusion. This is done by counting ordered set partitions where we distribute $n$ labelled items into $k$ distinguishable cells, none of which may be empty. The nodes of the poset for use with PIE represent subsets $P$ of $q$ elements of $[k]$  where  these cells remain empty, plus possibly more empty cells and having weight $(-1)^{|P|}$ This yields $$k!\times {n\brace k} = \sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (-1)^{q} (k-q)^n.$$ and it is a useful fact but not applicable to answer the question posed here.

Answer (score 0):

The generating functions are overkill for finding out how 6 numbers which are all 2, 3, or 4 can add up to 14. At minimum, six such numbers sum to 12, so you have 2 excess: either one 4 and five 2s, or two 3s and four 2s.

In the first case, you have four arms from a single vertex of degree 4, and you can vary the lengths of the arms for a total of 10 vertices. In the second case, you have two vertices of degree three connected by a path with zero to four vertices of degree 2, and the remaining two neighbors of each of the degree-3 vertices begin four arms to the leaves.

As far as the generating functions go, there seems to be a missing power of 6 in this line:

$$x^{12}(1+x+x^2)=14$$

but I think that was corrected in the following lines.

Comment: I think the problem is that using generating functions there're cases which are against conditions like having two 4-degree nodes, 4 3-degree nodes. But there're lots of cases to count manually so I believe a formula can be derived for this case